# how to change the log level to ERROR for systemd-resolved

Tags: server, rsyslog, systemd-resolved

I am using ubuntu 20.04, I configured `rsyslog` to  send/forward logs to a remote `syslog-ng` but I am getting to many `WARNING` message like this:

```
Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, 
retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
```

How could I increase the loglevel to be `ERROR` only for `systemd-resolved` or configure `rsyslog` to only forward only log levels > `WARNING`

Comment: You might be able to achieve this by doing the steps outlined here in this answer on Unix.SE but replace `debug` with `error` (UNTESTED) - https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/432077/5807

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I solve it, I created the file:

```
/etc/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service.d/override.conf
```

With contents:

```
[Service]
LogLevelMax=3
```

Comment: this does not work in 20.04 maybe the systemd version mattered

Answer (score 2):

You can change the log level of the resolver by issuing the following command (as root, *i.e.* using `sudo`):

```
resolvectl log-level debug
```

Substitute for `debug` the desired log level, *e.g.* `info` is the default.